# How do I hide the first view controller top bar

Tags: ios, hidden

I want to hide the top bar of the first view controller.

I know that I cannot just edit the file for that view controller since it's copyrighted by Apple. So I need to build a new controller file custom class, and attach that to the view controller that i want the top bar hidden for.

Then, how do I edit this newly-created .m file so that it hides the top bar for the view controller I want hidden?

Thank you! :)

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.  Perhaps you post a print screen of that view.

Comment: @user523234 I'm trying to hide the top bar of the very first view controller. My storyboard looks like this: Navigation Controller>ViewController1>ViewController2. And I want to hide the top bar on ViewController1 while seeing it on 2. It's the first screen on my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do the following:

In View Controller 1:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

In View Controller 2:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Put it where I said to put it.

Comment: I'm using storyboards though. Which file? @rmaddy

Comment: You put each in the respective .m file for the given view controller.

Comment: I'm looking for the .m file in the navigator and I don't see any .m file besides AppDelegate.m and main.m. @rmaddy

Comment: I don't use storyboards so I have no idea what steps you need to create the proper .m file for each view controller. But once you figure that out, add the code I posted.

Comment: do I need to create new .m files and new view controllers? @rmaddy

Comment: New .m files, yes. New view controllers, no.

Comment: And then assign the view controller to that new .m file with a custom class? See Below....

Comment: I've added a new .m file and assigned the view controller to that custom class, but there is no (void)viewWillAppear @rmaddy

Comment: Yes, that's why I said you need to add that code to the .m file. Paste the code from my answer (one method per .m).